# Why would rows in document-term matrix have only zeros (wrt topic modeling in R using LDA function)

Tags: r, text-mining

I am trying to implement topic modeling on a corpus of tweet. For this, I am using the `LDA()` function of the `topicmodels` package.

The document-term matrix on which I want to run the function is the following:

```
> dtm
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 31627, terms: 19225)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 177753/607851322
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 25
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

When I try to use the function with the following code `lda <- LDA(dtm, k = 5)`,
I get this error:

```
> lda <- LDA(dtm, k = 5) 
Error in LDA(dtm, k = 5) : 
  Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry
```

This presumably means that some of the rows in `dtm` consist only of 0s. However, how can that be? Wouldn't that mean the corresponding document is empty (has no words)? The only processing I did on the corpus of tweets before forming the term-document and document-term matrices was to remove punctuation, any numbers, stopwords (using the SMART list and a few of my own), and extra whitespaces. It is unlikely that a document (tweet) would have consisted only of the items removed. Therefore, why do some (many?) of the rows in `dtm` have only zeros?

Also, I am unable to clearly understand the significance and the underlying concept of the term "sparsity" and what a sparsity of 100% implies. Where should I look for an explanation?

Comment: Seems like there could easily be some tweets that contained only those items you removed, right? For example, a tweet that says "Yes!"

Comment: @paqmo: Normally, that would be true. However, the tweets that I am using were curated and consist of only health-related tweets by leading new agencies (BBC, NYT, MSNBC, etc.) Thus, it is unlikely that they would only consist of words that would be picked up and removed during the processing stage.

Comment: I see. You could use `which(apply(dtm , 1, sum) == 0)` and find out which row(s) are giving you the problem and then find the corresponding tweet.

Comment: @paqmo: I did check for that and yes, the resulting tweets were indeed made of terms that would be removed during processing! Thanks for the tip. However, I have a followup question. I used `which(apply(dtm2, 1, sum) == 0)` to search for the documents(rows) consisting of all zeros. This throws the following:  `2259  5265  5326  5482  6370  6449 14110 14347 15091 15102 15157 15528 15550 15729 23426`
 `2259  5265  5326  5482  6370  6449 14110 14347 15091 15102 15157 15528 15550 15729 23426 .....` Any idea why the row numbers are repeated in every case? This was true for all the rows.

Comment: hard to tell without your dtm, but my guess is that one set is the row number and the other set is the name of the document. If you don't provide explicit document names, `topicmodels` assigns the row number as the document name. Try assigning `tmp <- which(apply(dtm2, 1, sum) == 0)` and then checking with `str(tmp)` and see if something like `attr(*, "names")` is listed.